# Delphi SQL How to only display certain Dates out of a database

Tags: sql, delphi

Hey guys I'm not sure how to ask this I am fairly new to Delphi But I am trying to display a database through Delphi I am displaying a list of people and their dates of birth but I want Delphi to only display the people who were born in a certain year and I'm really not sure how to accomplish this, this is what I have so far but it's not really working.

```
adoQ.Active := false;
adoQ.SQL.Text := 'select SPELER, GEBOORTEDATUM from Tennis_Spelers WHERE GEBOORTEDATUM <> 00-00-1986';
adoQ.Open;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What server are you using, MS SQL?  If so, something like "WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, GEBOORTEDATUM) = 1988"

Comment: I'm not sure but like I said I am really new with this so I apologize if this is going to cause an inconvenience but I think it's MS

Comment: MS SqlServer or MS Access?

Comment: I Think it's MS Access

Comment: The Document is an access file and the ADO Connection provider is Microsoft jet 4.0 OLE

Comment: I don't use Access myself but according to google, DATEPART should work with it.  Give it a try ...

Comment: I Tried what you said but it gives an error as soon as I click the button the programming was done on.

Comment: I'm afraid "gives an error" doesn't tell readers anything useful.  What does the error message say (in English preferably)?  Also, we're not really supposed to conduct an extended conversation in SO comments ...

Comment: Porject1_p.exe raised exception class EOleException With message ' YEAR has no default value' process stopped use step or run to continue.

Comment: In that case, I think you'd better delete this question, and write a new one stating the SQL you're using and the error message and asking how to avoid it.

Comment: Is your question about `[delphi]` or `[sql]`? Please tag with care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use parameters :

```
adoQ.SQL.Text := 'select SPELER, GEBOORTEDATUM from Tennis_Spelers WHERE GEBOORTE =:a1'
adoQ.SQL.Paramaters('a1').asdate := datetimepicker1.date;
```

If you are not using datetimepicker then access will prompt you for the parameter.

Comment: nice way is to use two datetime pickers so you can select the datebetween.... Its more dynamic...like GEBOORTE BETWEEN :a1 AND =:a2 (a1 and a2 are datetimepickers)

Comment: This would show only people who were born exactly on that date. If the task is to show only people born in a given year, then you should use different approach.

Comment: Ok its only in a certain year and sorry Gedoorte-Birth Datum-Date

Comment: Actually, you are matching exact `DATE` whilst OP wants to match on `EXTRACT (YEAR FROM GEBOORTE) = :year_param`. An another option (more execution friendly) is to construct a `BETWEEN` operator.

Comment: Something to be aware of is that `TDateTimepicker.Date` will also return the current time as well as the selected date which can cause your query to return incorrect results, so remember to `Trunc` the date value(s) before passing them as query parameters.

Comment: You certainly do NOT "have to use parameters", and your solution only matches exactly one date, not a full year.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use parameters. For example, this or similar code should work on every database:

```
adoQ.SQL.Text := 'select SPELER, GEBOORTEDATUM from Tennis_Spelers WHERE GEBOORTEDATUM >= ''19740101'' AND GEBOORTEDATUM <= ''19741231''';
```

In MS Access, you might also try:

```
adoQ.SQL.Text := 'select SPELER, GEBOORTEDATUM from Tennis_Spelers WHERE GEBOORTEDATUM >= #01/01/1974# AND GEBOORTEDATUM <= #12/31/1974#';
```